# go mod vendor should not have @version error

Tags: go

After upgrading to go v1.18.1, `go mod vendor` returns a bunch of errors:

```
$ go mod vendor
bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/davecgh/go-spew@v1.1.1/spew: import path "bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/davecgh/go-spew@v1.1.1/spew" should not have @version
bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/dustin/go-humanize@v1.0.0: import path "bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/dustin/go-humanize@v1.0.0" should not have @version
bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/dustin/go-humanize@v1.0.0/english: import path "bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/dustin/go-humanize@v1.0.0/english" should not have @version
bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/eknkc/amber@v0.0.0-20171010120322-cdade1c07385: import path "bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/eknkc/amber@v0.0.0-20171010120322-cdade1c07385" should not have @version
bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/eknkc/amber@v0.0.0-20171010120322-cdade1c07385/amberc: import path "bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/eknkc/amber@v0.0.0-20171010120322-cdade1c07385/amberc" should not have @version
bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/eknkc/amber@v0.0.0-20171010120322-cdade1c07385/parser: import path "bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/eknkc/amber@v0.0.0-20171010120322-cdade1c07385/parser" should not have @version
bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/jmespath/go-jmespath@v0.0.0-20180206201540-c2b33e8439af: import path "bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/jmespath/go-jmespath@v0.0.0-20180206201540-c2b33e8439af" should not have @version
bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/jmespath/go-jmespath@v0.0.0-20180206201540-c2b33e8439af/cmd/jpgo: import path "bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/jmespath/go-jmespath@v0.0.0-20180206201540-c2b33e8439af/cmd/jpgo" should not have @version
bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/jmespath/go-jmespath@v0.0.0-20180206201540-c2b33e8439af/fuzz: import path "bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/jmespath/go-jmespath@v0.0.0-20180206201540-c2b33e8439af/fuzz" should not have @version
bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/joho/godotenv@v1.3.0: import path "bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/joho/godotenv@v1.3.0" should not have @version
bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/joho/godotenv@v1.3.0/autoload: import path "bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/joho/godotenv@v1.3.0/autoload" should not have @version
bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/joho/godotenv@v1.3.0/cmd/godotenv: import path "bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/joho/godotenv@v1.3.0/cmd/godotenv" should not have @version
bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/klauspost/pgzip@v1.2.5: import path "bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/klauspost/pgzip@v1.2.5" should not have @version
bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/mattn/go-zglob@v0.0.2-0.20191112051448-a8912a37f9e7: import path "bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/mattn/go-zglob@v0.0.2-0.20191112051448-a8912a37f9e7" should not have @version
bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/mattn/go-zglob@v0.0.2-0.20191112051448-a8912a37f9e7/cmd/zglob: import path "bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/mattn/go-zglob@v0.0.2-0.20191112051448-a8912a37f9e7/cmd/zglob" should not have @version
bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/mattn/go-zglob@v0.0.2-0.20191112051448-a8912a37f9e7/fastwalk: import path "bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/mattn/go-zglob@v0.0.2-0.20191112051448-a8912a37f9e7/fastwalk" should not have @version
bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/mattn/go-zglob@v0.0.3: import path "bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/mattn/go-zglob@v0.0.3" should not have @version
bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/mattn/go-zglob@v0.0.3/cmd/zglob: import path "bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/mattn/go-zglob@v0.0.3/cmd/zglob" should not have @version
bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/mattn/go-zglob@v0.0.3/fastwalk: import path "bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/mattn/go-zglob@v0.0.3/fastwalk" should not have @version
bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/nfnt/resize@v0.0.0-20180221191011-83c6a9932646: import path "bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/nfnt/resize@v0.0.0-20180221191011-83c6a9932646" should not have @version
bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/pkg/errors@v0.9.1: import path "bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/pkg/errors@v0.9.1" should not have @version
bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/pmezard/go-difflib@v1.0.0/difflib: import path "bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/pmezard/go-difflib@v1.0.0/difflib" should not have @version
bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/satori/go.uuid@v1.2.1-0.20181028125025-b2ce2384e17b: import path "bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/satori/go.uuid@v1.2.1-0.20181028125025-b2ce2384e17b" should not have @version
bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/tylerb/graceful@v1.2.15: import path "bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/tylerb/graceful@v1.2.15" should not have @version
bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/tylerb/graceful@v1.2.15/tests: import path "bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/tylerb/graceful@v1.2.15/tests" should not have @version
bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/negroni@v1.0.0: import path "bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/negroni@v1.0.0" should not have @version
bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/go-playground/assert.v1@v1.2.1: import path "bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/go-playground/assert.v1@v1.2.1" should not have @version
bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9@v9.29.1: import path "bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9@v9.29.1" should not have @version
bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9@v9.29.1/non-standard/validators: import path "bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9@v9.29.1/non-standard/validators" should not have @version
bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9@v9.29.1/translations/en: import path "bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9@v9.29.1/translations/en" should not have @version
bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9@v9.29.1/translations/fr: import path "bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9@v9.29.1/translations/fr" should not have @version
bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9@v9.29.1/translations/id: import path "bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9@v9.29.1/translations/id" should not have @version
bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9@v9.29.1/translations/ja: import path "bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9@v9.29.1/translations/ja" should not have @version
bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9@v9.29.1/translations/nl: import path "bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9@v9.29.1/translations/nl" should not have @version
bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9@v9.29.1/translations/pt_BR: import path "bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9@v9.29.1/translations/pt_BR" should not have @version
bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9@v9.29.1/translations/zh: import path "bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9@v9.29.1/translations/zh" should not have @version
bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9@v9.29.1/translations/zh_tw: import path "bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9@v9.29.1/translations/zh_tw" should not have @version
bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/unrolled/render.v1@v1.0.0: import path "bitbucket.org/jigspace/jigpipeline/lib/go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/unrolled/render.v1@v1.0.0" should not have @version
```

With go 1.17.9 it worked okay. What should I do?

Comment: Try removing your vendor folder before running go mod vendor.

Comment: done that, same errors

Comment: What steps exactly have you taken? Perhaps you have somehow corrupted the module cache? Maybe just remove all those files and re-fetch the dependencies.

Comment: I have done `go ​clean -modcache` and I'm still having those errors, `go mod tidy` also has the same errors.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the error occur after upgrade a old project to `go 1.19`.

Here is what I did to fix it:

- First delete `pkg/` dir of project, if any.
- Then run cmd:

  ```
  go clean -modcache
  go mod tidy
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I deleted lib/go directory and it works now.

Comment: deleted lib/go? Can you explain it briefly

Answer (score 1):

Just add `-e` to tidy command to ignore errors

```
go mod tidy -e
```

Comment: This doesn't work